# Compare two date not working properly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to compare two date:

Start

> Thu, 29 Oct 2015 18:00:00 GMT

End

> Fri, 30 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT

Simply

```
if(end > start)
{
   alert('work');
}
else
{
   alert('not work');
}
```

But the condition fall to not work.
See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a83ob6dy/4/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(function(){
    start = moment(moment("Thu, 29 Oct 2015 18:00:00 GMT").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + "18:00").format("ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + " GMT";
    end = moment(moment("Fri, 30 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + "00:00").format("ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + " GMT";
    $('#divLocal').html(start);
    $('#divLocal2').html(end);
    if (new Date(end) > new Date(start))         
    {
     snippet.log("work");
    }
    else
    {
     snippet.log("not work");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="divLocal"></div>    
<div id='divLocal2'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (new Date(end) > new Date(start)) {}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a83ob6dy/5/

Answer (score 1):

You try to compare strings, you should compare `Date` objects

Answer (score 0):

> Right now you are comparing strings. To compare dateds in `moment`, Use `moment()` method instead like this:

```
start=moment(start);
end=moment(end);
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a83ob6dy/4/

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to compare the formatted strings, rather than `moment` or `Date` objects.  If you are indeed using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), then you should just be comparing `moment` objects by using the `isBefore` or `isAfter` functions, rather than the comparison operators.

Also, you should be providing an *input* format string during parsing.  Otherwise you will be falling-back to the `Date` constructor, and will get a deprecation warning message in your console.

In the below example, `fmt` is defined once, then used as both the input format and as the output format.  (This is the RFC822 format, which you should try to avoid.  If possible use the ISO8601 format instead.)

Also notice that I use the `moment.utc` function, to interpret the input explicitly in UTC, rather than rely on the "GMT" abbreviation.  This is somewhat important.

```js
$(function() {
  var fmt = "ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]";
  start = moment.utc("Thu, 29 Oct 2015 18:00:00 GMT", fmt);
  end = moment.utc("Fri, 30 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT", fmt);
  $('#divLocal').html(start.format(fmt));
  $('#divLocal2').html(end.format(fmt));

  if (end.isAfter(start)) {
    alert("work");
  } else {
    alert("not work");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="divLocal"></div>
<div id='divLocal2'></div>
```

([Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a83ob6dy/9/))